# Reverting most top n commits in git

Tags: git

How do I revert the top 3 commits in git?

For example:

```
git revert -n master~3..HEAD
```

Is this the correct syntax?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? You can always recover to your current state if the results aren't what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the bellow command for reverting last three commmits, assuming you are in master branch.

You should use tha branch name instead of `HEAD` in your command.

```
git revert master~3..master
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you want. If your code is not yet pushed to master, I prefer to use `git reset` to undo commits, and you can use `git reset --soft` to undo commits, but leave the files untouched, which usually happens if you want to change order of commits, or fix an older commit (before pushing it to master).

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

will revert the last 3 commits and leave the code (to edit and re-commit later).

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

will revert the last commits and discard all changes to files.

`git revert` will normally create a new commit and leave the git history intact, which in general (before pushing to master) you do not want, but it is perfect if the code was already pushed to master.

```
git revert HEAD~3
```

will create a new commit that reverts the last three commits.